# Get percentage from results from two case results

Tags: mysql, query, case, sum

How i can get percentage from two resuts from case staments?

```
   SELECT *,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN estado_rep >=11 and RELATION=1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as pendiente,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN estado_rep >=11 and RELATION=2 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as realizada
   from AVERIES GROUP BY ID_AV
```

Result query now

```
aa  bb  cc       pendiente   realizada
-----------      ---------   ---------
xxx xxx xxx          2          1
xxx xxx xxx          3          0
```

I want add a query percentage to root query.

(realizada*100)/(realizada+pendiente) as Progress

```
 aa  bb  cc       pendiente   realizada   progress
 --  --  --       ---------   ---------   --------
 xxx xxx xxx          2          1           33%
 xxx xxx xxx          3          0           0%
```

Thanks

Comment: `COUNT(CASE WHEN estado_rep >=11 and RELATION=1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)` can be shortened to `SUM(estado_rep >=11 and RELATION=1)`.

Comment: If `estado_rep >=11` is common to all the columns, then consider removing it from the `CASEs` and add it to a `WHERE` clause at the end.

Answer (score 0):

i found it

```
    SELECT *,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN estado_rep >=11 and relacion=1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as pendiente,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN estado_rep >=11 and relacion=2 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as realizada,
   truncate(COUNT(CASE WHEN estado_rep >=11 and relacion=2 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)*100/(COUNT(CASE WHEN estado_rep >=11 and relacion=2 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)+ COUNT(CASE WHEN estado_rep >=11 and relacion=1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)),2) as Total
from AVERIES GROUP BY ID_AV
```

Comment: Perhaps `ROUND`?  I'm suspicious when I see "66" for 2/3.